# The countable chain condition in products

Tags: set-theory

I have a question about the proof of the theorem $\left[ \forall \text{ finite } J \subseteq I \left[ \prod\limits_{j \in J} X_j \text{ is c.c.c.} \right] \Rightarrow \prod\limits_{i \in I} X_i \text{ is c.c.c.} \right]$.

The proof is described at here: http://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/docs/other/ccc_products.pdf

I can't understand why he can apply the $\Delta$-system lemma to the collection ${\cal A} = \left\{ F_U : U \in {\cal U} \right\}$ to find an uncountable $\Delta$-system ${\cal B} \subseteq {\cal A}$ (at page 4). Because we have to make sure ${\cal A}$ is uncountable beforehand.

However I think that is not obvious since mapping$: U \mapsto F_U$ is not injective generally.

How can I make sure that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $F \subseteq I$ finite, the set $\mathcal{U}_F := \{U \in \mathcal{U} : F_U = F\}$ can be identified as a set of disjoint open subsets of $\prod_{i \in F} X_i$. This space is assumed to be ccc, so $\mathcal{U}_F$ is countable. If $\mathcal{A} = \{F_n : n < \omega\}$ is countable, then $\mathcal{U} = \bigcup_{n<\omega} \mathcal{U}_{F_n}$ is also countable, contrary to our hypothesis.

Comment: thanks for your help! I completely understood.