# The countable chain condition in products(question 2)

Tags: set-theory

(question 1 is [The countable chain condition in products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4675593/the-countable-chain-condition-in-products))

I have a question about the proof of the theorem:
$\left[ \forall \text{ finite } J \subseteq I \left[ \prod\limits_{j \in J} X_j \text{ is c.c.c.} \right] \Rightarrow \prod\limits_{i \in I} X_i \text{ is c.c.c.} \right]$.
The proof is described at here: http://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/docs/other/ccc_products.pdf

I can't understand why we may assume without loss of generality that each of the sets in ${\cal U}$ are basic open subsets of the product topology(at 2nd paragraph).

Comment: Questions should be as self-contained as possible. Please include the proof as the link may disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition of basic open sets, each $U \in \mathcal{U}$ contains a basic open set $V_U \subseteq U$. Clearly if $U,U' \in \mathcal{U}$ and $U \cap U' = \emptyset$, then $V_U \cap V_{U'} = \emptyset$. Thus $\{V_U : U \in \mathcal{U}\}$ is a collection of disjoint basic open sets with the same cardinality as $\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: thanks for help. that arguement contain AC.